# PHP acusa que Curl não está instalado

Tags: php

Eu baixei o .exe do site oficial, adiconei a variável de sistema e testei. Tudo funcionando.

Mas quando vou no meu programa em PHP sempre dá o mesmo erro:

> **Fatal error:** Call to undefined function curl_init()

Meu código no trecho em que dá o problema:

```
 <?php
    $url_recepient = "https://api.pagar.me/1/recipients";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_recepient);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 ?>
```

E agora não sei se é erro do meu código ou eu que não instalei direito.

Comment: Então, na versão 7xx que utilizo, procurei por curl no arquivo php.ini, apareceu ;extension=curl , só removi o ponto e virgula e reiniciei o servidor local

Answer (score 3):

Isso ocorre porque a [**biblioteca cURL**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php) não está instalada e habilitada.

**Para habilitar no windows:**

Crie um arquivo chamado `info.php` com o conteúdo:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Acesse a URL do arquivo citado acima e localize o arquivo o caminho do arquivo `php.ini` especificado em `Loaded Configuration File`, então abra o arquivo 'php.ini' informado e remova o ponto e vírgula da linha:

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

Deve ficar assim:

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

Salve o arquivo `php.ini`.

Copie os arquivos `php_curl.dll`,  `ssleay32.dll` e `libeay32.dll` para a sua pasta `Windows/system32`

Reinicie o servidor web e faça os testes.

**Para instalar e habilitar no linux (Debian/Ubuntu):**

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**Para instalar e habilitar no linux (CentOS):**

```
yum install php-curl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**Caso tudo tenha corrido bem:**

Se tudo correu bem, você deverá encontrar algo semelhante à imagem abaixo em seu `phpinfo();`, informando que a biblioteca cURL está instalada e informando suas configurações

[image: phpinfo(); exibindo seção cURL]]

**Se estiver executando via Prompt**

Use o "`-c caminho_do_php.ini`"

```
php -c C:\php\php.ini -S localhost:8080
```

Comment: Não tem o arquivo php.ini, tem dois outros com os seguitnes nomes: php.ini-PRODUCTION e php.ini-DEVELOPMENT ai eu fui em ambos e fiz o que tu disse mas não resolveu

Comment: Fiz isso e não adiantou... Será que é pq estou usando o servidor de teste que vem junto as novas versões do PHP e não o Apache?

Comment: Eu estou usando o nativo que vem junto no PHP (digito no prompt: php -S localhost:8080 e testo por lá) e na phpinfo() aparece todas as informações do php como era para aparecer

Comment: Uma coisa importante, lembre de copiar os arquivos `php_curl.dll`,  `ssleay32.dll` e `libeay32.dll` para a sua pasta `Windows/system32`